# JSON with double qoute, how to manage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html-parsing

Well im working with an web application who 
Well, I'm working with an Web application that returns a String in JSON object format, something like that:

```
[{"name":"Luigi","Last_Name":"Car"},{"name":"Mario","Last_Name":"Bros"}]
```

But the problem is when a field has a double quote in it, by example:

```
[{"name":"Luigi"","Last_Name":"Car"},{"name":"Mario","Last_Name":"Bros"}]
```

(Luigi has a " )

When the fields don't have quotes, I manage this String with this line:

```
JSON.parse(response.d)
```

and it works perfectly, but the problems as I mentioned before is when some field has this character.

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something wrong when you create the json. If you are creating it manually...don't. All languages have serializers for arrays and objects to json and will escape any quotes providing only valid json

Comment: if you want to escape double quote in JSON use \\ to escape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PoorChristmas, there are multiple ways to solve this.

1. If you are generating the JSON then simply add escape characters for any double quotes like below
   [{"name":"Luigi\\"","Last_Name":"Car"},{"name":"Mario","Last_Name":"Bros"}]
2. If you don't have control on the generation of the JSON, then try to replace any multiple double quotes with single double quote using below logic

```js
var a = '[{"name":"Luigi"""""""""""""","Last_Name":"Car"},{"name":"Mario","Last_Name":"Bros"}]';
var b = a.split("");
var c = "";
for (i = 1; i < b.length; i++) {
    if (b[i] == '"') {
        if (b[i - 1] == '{' || b[i + 1] == ':' || b[i - 1] == ':' || b[i + 1] == ',' || b[i - 1] == ',' || b[i + 1] == '}') {
            c = c + b[i];
        }
    } else {
        c = c + b[i];
    }
}

console.log(c)
```

Comment: @PoorChristmas give it a thumbs up if it works. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The following characters are reserved in JSON and must be properly escaped to be used in strings:

```
Backspace is replaced with \b.
Form feed is replaced with \f.
Newline is replaced with \n.
Carriage return is replaced with \r.
Tab is replaced with \t.
Double quote is replaced with \"
Backslash is replaced with \\
```